# Determining which attributes were modified in an ember-data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any way of telling exactly which attributes were changed on a dirty record using ember-data?

The docs show a changedAttributes method, but I can’t use that directly because I want to bind it in a template.

I could set up observers for every field to get an event when they are updated, but that seems like a tedious solution, I was wondering if there was an easier way.

**Edit**: My use case is basically that I'm trying to indicate which fields were modified in an "edit" form.

Answer (score 0):

There is an object `_attributes` on the record that has all the modified properties/values, you could use Em.keys on it for them all.